# Using a slider in Android Studio composable

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, slider

I'm trying to write an Android App using Android Studio.

It seems the latest android studio will only allow Kotlin.

I want a function that will produce a slider that will take a start value between 0 and 1023 and return a new value in the same range.

I found an example but am completely lost (I'm used to C)

This is what I currently have,

```
@Composable
fun getValue():Float{
    return(513f)
}


@Preview
@Composable
fun SliderMinimalExample(){
    var sliderPosition by remember{mutableFloatStateOf(512f)}
    sliderPosition=getValue()   //returns 513
    Column {
        Slider(
            value = sliderPosition,
            onValueChange = { sliderPosition = it.roundToInt().toFloat() },
            //steps=0,
            valueRange=0f..1023f
        )
        Text(text = sliderPosition.toString())
    }
}
```

This kinda works and starts at 512 but then changes to 513 as it fetches the value from getValue.
However, I can't move the slider, it's stuck on 513.
Android studio adds extra bits that don't show in the copy/paste above,
I.E.
[image: Added Greterthan or eual sign.]

Can anyone point me in the direction of an example that I might understand?

Thanks,

Comment: why did you write `sliderPosition=getValue()`?

Comment: At first I tried to add a parameter to the function but it seems that's not allowed. Granted, I should have just put sliderPosition=513F

Comment: No if you assign a number to the sliderPosition's value, your slider will be fixed on that number. it is because when you touch the thumb of slider and try to change the position, `SliderMinimalExample` will be called repeatedly and your hard coded number (513) will be assigned to the Slider again and again so the slider seems to be stuck. if you want to set an initial value, just change 512 inside of `mutableFloatStateOf`. if you have any question feel free to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added a method to get the value of the SliderPosition:

```
@Composable
fun getValue():Float{
    return(513f)
}
```

You don't need to do that at all. That is why the value is always 513.

Remove that method and the call to it and have this inside your composable:

```
@Composable
fun SliderMinimalExample() {
    var sliderPosition by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(512f) }
    Column {
        Slider(
            value = sliderPosition,
            onValueChange = { sliderPosition = it.roundToInt().toFloat() },
            valueRange=0f..1023f
        )
        Text(text = sliderPosition.toString())
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

To set an initial value, you can either use a ViewModel that interacts with your Activity and will update it when the data is received from Bluetooth. This can be done in several ways using LiveData, Flow and more.

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state)

Comment: Thank you, that's now working - I obviously understand this less than I thought. How would I set an initial value? I get a value via Bluetooth and wish to change that value so I can't put an initial value in mutableFloatStateOf().

Comment: @PommieMike - If my answer helped you, please mark it as such so that others can find it more easily. As for your second question, I'll edit my answer to reflect that.